# How to set Margin of a textview in a relative layout

Tags: android, textview, android-relativelayout, layoutparams

I've read a few answers about setting margins of a textview programmatically when the parent is a LinearLayout, but in my case i need to set margin of a textview in a relativelayout

here's what i tried and didn't work:

description is my textview in the following code:

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params1 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        params1.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, idsArray[i]);
        params1.addRule(RelativeLayout.LEFT_OF, R.id.imageButtonCamera);
        params1.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, R.id.divider);
        params1.setMargins(8, 8, 8, 8)

        description.setLayoutParams(params1);
```

Any hint ?

UDPATE:

my layout xml file:

the TextView with id textViewTip is the one i need to change relative and margins attributes.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/item_layout_main"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@drawable/layer_car_background" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textViewItemTitle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"
    android:text="Large Text"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

 <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageViewTitle"
    android:layout_width="32dp"
    android:layout_height="32dp"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textViewItemTitle"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_action_expand" />

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayoutExpandable"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
    android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textViewItemTitle" >

    <View
        android:id="@+id/divider"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_below="@id/divider"
        android:id="@+id/imageViewItem"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="133dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewTip"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageViewItem"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageViewItem"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="22dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="22dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imageButtonCamera"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageViewItem"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextDescription"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/textViewTip"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/enter_own_description"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="32dp"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_marginRight="12dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_ok" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkBox1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkBox2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/checkBox1"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/checkBox1"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/imageView1" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="32dp"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editTextDescription"
        android:layout_marginRight="17dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imageView2"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_repair" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/checkBox2"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/checkBox2"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:text="@string/estimated_cost"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextEstCost"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/checkBox1"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/checkBox2"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_marginRight="24dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButtonCamera"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textViewTip"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_action_camera" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Does your description layout have a layout_margin attribute already specified in xml?

Comment: Yes should i remove it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params1 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,  RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    params1.setMargins(8, 8, 8, 8);

    description.setLayoutParams(params1);
```

try this. as it is working now and will provide margins.

look my updated ans. from the xml the margin layout working well you can set the margin from xml. as

```
   <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textViewTip"
    android:textSize="12sp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageViewItem"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageViewItem"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="22dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="22dp"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imageButtonCamera"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageViewItem"
    android:text="Changable" />
```

it is working and if you want to change the margins programmatically then use the following code.

```
    LayoutParams p=new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    TextView tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textViewTip);

    p.setMargins(30, 30, 30, 30);
    tv.setLayoutParams(p);
```

Comment: Thats what i did first

Comment: if you have already specified attributes in xml then you have to get that attributes and modify them then set the layout params on the description layout

Comment: I cannot set both params to my textview. If i set the marginlayoutparams i'm going to loose my relative params.

Comment: yes, it is thats why use one method either through xml or code.
post the xml file.

Comment: look my answer. if it is providing help then accept it and feel free to ask if there is any query.

Comment: I have no doubt that this would work in a linearlayout but you see... The imageViewItem id refered in my textview changes id in code. For that reason i need to still be relative to this imageview by creating a relativelayout params and call left of with new ID. But it seems that setMargins in my relativelayout params is not working.

Comment: dear i just copy your xml file and try that provided code and it is working on your relative layout. did you try this?